# Apache Commons Lang comes by default with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, string-utils

I have a requirement in my project to delete from build.gradle the **implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'** and instead use apache commons lang (which comes by default with Spring Boot).

I don't know the package structure so that I can import StringUtils from the described library. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the API docs.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html

Search for "StringUtils"

Comment: Also, you sure you don't want the most current version, which is 3.11?

Comment: In the end I used the one from version 3.0. Thank you anyway !